# Biztalk 2013 Administration Console symbol / icon by receive location

Tags: icons, biztalk, symbols, biztalk-2013

Can someone please explain to me this icon / symbol with the check-mark on a receive location in the BizTalk 2013 Administration Console?

### [image: Receive Location Icon]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means your receive location is the primary receive location of your receive port.

If you add a second receive location to a receive port, you'll have the same icon but without the checkmark.

Comment: Thanks! Very quick reply.